# Extract files from GBQ to GCS without csv header using bq command line

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to run a command like:

```
bq extract <source_table> <destination_uris>
```

and use a flag to export without the csv header?  Similar to the API flag mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972432/transfer-large-file-from-google-bigquery-to-google-cloud-storage), but without using the API- just via `bq extract...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
bq extract --noprint_header <source_table> <destination_uris>
```

You can find this option from the output of:

```
bq help extract

[...]
--[no]print_header: Whether to print header rows for formats that have headers.
Prints headers by default.
```