# Remove header from query result in bq command line

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a query `$(bq query --format=csv "select value from $BQConfig where parameter = 'Columnwidth'")` .

The output of the query in csv format is :

`value
3 4 6 8`

here i want to get only the result `3 4 6 8` not the `value` which is just a header.

I have gone through google document and found that `--noprint_header` works only for `bq extract`. i didnt find anything for `bq query`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assigning the output of a BQ query to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45351830/assigning-the-output-of-a-bq-query-to-variable)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837581/extract-files-from-gbq-to-gcs-without-csv-header-using-bq-command-line/36842915#36842915 solves this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are on a bash shell, you could use `sed` or `awk` to skip the first lines:

```
 bq query --format=csv "SELECT 1 x" | sed "2 d"
```

Or:

```
 bq query --format=csv "SELECT 1 x" | awk 'NR>2'
```

Comment: ```bq query --format=csv "SELECT 1 x" | tail -n +2``` also does the trick

Comment: I seem to require `awk 'NR>1'` (?)

Answer (score -3):

You can use the `--skip_leading_rows` argument (source : [Create a table from a file](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool#creatingtablefromfile))

Comment: I changed my query as `$(bq query --skip_leading_rows=1 --format=csv "select value from $BQConfig where parameter = 'Columnwidth'")`. But now i am getting error as `FATAL Flags parsing error: Unknown command line flag 'skip_leading_rows'` . Please let me know if you need any other information

Comment: Why don't you just load the csv's into BQ and the query it? When loading you can `bq load --source_format=CSV --skip_leading_rows=1` or even use the auto detect schema flag. Then querying will be trivial

Comment: `skip_leading_rows` is for `load`, not `query`.